# Calculate the first pay date between two dates if given those two dates and any previous pay date

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to simplify the regular updating of our monthly home budget spreadsheet by removing the need to manually calculate what the first pay date will be within a monthly period.

If given the start and end date of a monthly period eg; **20/April/2021-19/May/2021**, and if pay dates are every **14 days**, and if a previous pay date is provided as **25/March/2021**, is it possible to calculate the first pay date within that monthly period (eg; to return **22/April/2021**)?

Once I have the first pay date within a monthly period, I just calculate the second pay date as CellWithFirstPayDate+14 days, and I just repeat that again for the third pay date in a month which only occurs twice a year.

I have seen related solutions which can calculate the number of pay dates in a given period, based on rounding, etc, but not a solution which can calculate actual dates of any of those pay dates.

Thanks.

Comment: Excel has a function [`DATEVALUE()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/datevalue-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252) which returns the date serial number for a given date. If you get paid every 14 days, then every date whose DATEVALUE() modulo 14 is the same as the DATEVALUE() of a known pay date will also be a pay date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breaking this down, the step in the middle is "how far into the 14 day pay period is the start date". That's the number of days since the previous pay date, minus lots of 14s until you get a remainder - which is what the MOD function does (return the remainder when one number is divided by another).
From there you know how many more days until the next pay day - it's 14 minus the answer above. So, in pseudo-code to avoid getting bogged down in cell references:

```
=PeriodStartDate + 14 - MOD(PeriodStartDate-LastPayDate,14)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is spot on and makes total sense when broken down!